# Extract key-values from a dictionary and dump them into parent dictionary with "aggregate" method of "Pymongo" and '$project' command of "MongoDB"

Tags: python, mongodb, list, dictionary, pymongo

***PROBLEM:***

I have a collection with the following document format:

```
{ 
   { "_id": 1234,
    "Processes": [
         "0": { "0_0": aaaa , "0_1": bbbb },
         "1": { "1_0": cccc, "1_1": dddd },
         "2": { "2_0": eeee, "2_1": ffff},
     ]},
   { "_id": 5678,
    "processes": [
         "0": { "0_0": gggg, "0_1": hhhh},
         "1": { "1_0": iiii, "1_1": jjjj},
         "2": { "2_0": kkkk, "2_1": mmmm},
     ]}
}
```

I have developed the following sentence to create a list whose elements are all processes separately:

```
cursor_processes = collection.aggregate([
        {
            '$unwind':"$processes"
        },
        {
            '$project': {
                "_id": 1,
                "processes": 1
            }
        }
])

results = [i for i in cursor_processes]
```

Analysing the output of the function, we can see that the result is as follows:

```
[{
   "_id": 1234,
   "processes": { "0_0": yyyy , "0_1": bbbb }
},
{
   "_id": 1234,
   "Processes": { "1_0": cccc, "1_1": dddd }
}, ...]
```

But what I am looking to get is a list with the following format:

```
[{
   "_id": 1234,
   "0_0": yyyy , 
   "0_1": bbbb
},
{
   "_id": 1234,
   "1_0": cccc , 
   "1_1": dddd
}, ...]
```

***VERSIONS, LIBRARIES, FUNCTIONS AND METHODS:***

- Python 3.9
- from pymongo import MongoClient
- import json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right track. You just have to replace `$project` with `$replaceRoot` which contains `$mergeObjects` operator.

```
cursor_processes = collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$processes"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "_id": "$_id"
          },
          "$processes"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/khIOBhgjlHv)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I finally got the format I wanted =). I didn't know "$replaceRoot" nor "$mergeObjects", although this last one is similar to Pandas "merge".

Comment: @AngelRivasHidalgo glad that it helped. Don't forget to upvote the answer to help others.